# ReportBuilder access violation when trying to print

Tags: delphi, reportbuilder

I have a problem if you view the report in the Delphi Project
Let the message that appears:

> Access violation at address 00CEE75D in module 'OP.exe'. Read of address 00000000.Op.exe

This message does not appear on all environments

I had the file [EurekaLog file](https://www.mediafire.com/?7z3xcssrx9h68xq)

```
Report1.DeviceType := 'dtScreen';
Report1.Print;
```

Comment: There is a bug in `OP.exe` at virtual address `00CEE75D`.

Comment: Nothing we can tell you except you are trying to dereference a `nil` pointer. Post the relevant code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off
this bug appears occasionally, which means it doesn't come up all the time.
this issue came up dozens of times in variable situations, sometimes the error disappeared after rebooting or restarting the program itself.

multiple error logs were reported on ReportBuilder's support forum
they technically said the bug is out there and can't be fixed.

Answer (score 0):

The Eureka log call stack seems to indicate a problem in method `TppForm.Showmodal`:

```
|007DF2C3|OP.exe   |ppForms.pas  |TppForm        |ShowModal      |682[10]  |
|0093988A|OP.exe   |ppProd.pas   |TppProducer    |PrintToScreen  |1788[24] |
```

Based on your comment, the offending code is

```
TppForm Result := inherited ShowModal;
```

It looks like there is an invalid call to a not-yet created instance of TppForm.

Comment: Surely this would be better as a comment as it's not really an answer?

Comment: i am tracking error
TppForm
Result := inherited ShowModal;

Comment: @PreetSangha ok reduced my answer to the meat